# BigQuery REGEX get text between 2 characters

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

From this string :

```
gs://analytics_models_from_g_rdd_ga/9g653798d-7e13-4238-55443-6db72ace9911$$$$events_today.csv
```

I'm trying to extract this text :

```
9g653798d-7e13-4238-55443-6db72ace9911
```

and in separate REGEX function `events_today`

The rolls for the first string:

1. The string will always end with $$$$.
2. The string will always start with ga/.
3. The extracted text length can be changed.

I sew several tutorials and red regex references but still not succeed
I thought the solution will be `/\\s*(.*?)\\s*$$$$` but is not.

In general, to extract a string between 2 strings

Comment: Dollar signs have special meaning,; they are called anchors. You need to escape them like this `\\$\\$\\$\\$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In general**, to match any string between two specific chars, you can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r"<CHAR>(.*?)<CHAR>")
```

To match between `/` and `$`, you can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r"/(.*?)\$")
```

Also, see  the list of chars that must be escaped in a regex at [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078/3832970)

**Here,** you can use

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r".*ga/([^/$]*)\${4}.*", r"\1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gDLsX8/2).

The identical, but a bit simplified since `.*` will become redundant, pattern can be used in `REGEGEXP_EXTRACT`:

```py
REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, r"ga/([^/$]*)\${4}")
```

Pattern details:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `ga/`  - `ga` and a slash
- `([^/$]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `/` and `$`
- `\${4}` - four `$` symbols
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The replacement is the Group 1 backreference, `\1`, that replaces the whole match with the contents of the group.

Comment: And for the second string 
`REGEXP_REPLACE(_FILE_NAME, r".*ga/([^/$]*)\${4}(.*)\.csv", r"\2")`
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select regexp_extract(txt, r'ga/(.*?)\${4}')
```

if to apply to sample from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I get this 9g653798d-7e13-4238-55443-6db72ace9911$$$$events_today.csv

Comment: looks like SO's markup hid the \ char - i updated answer to fix this